# the distinction appeared much clearer

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

> Concepts of nature are always cultural statements. This may not strike Europeans as much of an insight, for Europe’s landscape is so much of a blend. But in the new worlds ― ‘new’ at least to Europeans ― the distinction **appeared much clearer** not only to European settlers and visitors but also to their descendants. Hence the fond conceit of primeval nature untrammelled by human associations which could later find expression in a reverence for wilderness.

[Source](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=%22Hence+the+fond+conceit+of+primeval+nature+untrammelled+by+human+associations+which+could+later+find+expression+in+a+reverence+for+wilderness.+ecological%22&biw=412&bih=774&tbm=bks&ei=__jDYLrkDOXxhwPSzbGoDg&oq=%22Hence+the+fond+conceit+of+primeval+nature+untrammelled+by+human+associations+which+could+later+find+expression+in+a+reverence+for+wilderness.+ecological%22&gs_lcp=Cg9tb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXNlcnAQA1DYMliRnAFg7J4BaABwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEPoAEBqgEZbW9iaWxlLWd3cy13aXotc2VycC1tb2Rlc8ABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-serp)

---

It seems to me that "**appeared**" means "to start to be seen".

When the verb *appear* is used to mean the meaning, an adjective can't come immediately after the verb *appear*.

I'm not sure about the grammatical construction of "**appeared much clearer**".

Comment: This is the other meaning of _appear_ - 'seem to be'. I'm not sure what distinction the author is talking about; presumably, between environments modified by humans and complete wilderness.

Comment: You've made three statements, but I don't see a clear question. Are you asking what the meaning of "appear" is? Have you checked other dictionary definitions to see if they fit the context?

Comment: @gotube No, I'm not asking. Yes, I have checked. However, it seemed to me that "**appeared**" didn't mean "seem to be".

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss What is your question then? If you're not actually asking something that we can answer, this should be closed.

Comment: @gotube What I'd like to know was if "appeared" means "to start to be seen" or "seem to be".